# ASP.VB Complex IF statement

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, if-statement

I'm getting an intellisenxe error saying that the statement below is expecting a ')' and is positioning the correction ater the parenthesis following "Approved".  I'm not familiar with this IF syntax and I can't seem to make the correction; trial and error isn't working ;o))  Thanks in advance.

```
If (reader.Item("Approved"), True, False) = 0), (reader.Item("DoNotDisplay"), False, False) = 0)) Then

End if
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? This syntax is very odd. Is this someone else's code? Did it ever work?

Comment: It looks like VB ternary operator but you later messed up. Simply state what you want to do and get correction

Comment: Yes, this is someone else's very old code that I am trying to move to .Net Framework 3.5 from 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
If ((reader.Item("Approved") = True) AND (reader.Item("DoNotDisplay") = False)) Then 

End if
```

Comment: I wasn't sure about the intent of the author, but that does look good and the syntax gets rid of the Intellisense error.  This is VERY OLD code which I'm trying to update.  Thank you!

Comment: @Susan Yeah, it's pretty tough to tell what they were going for.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like yuo have a parenthesis in the wrong spot, and they don't encompass the entire IF statement, so Intellisense is taking its best guess but is getting tripped up by the comma.

Try this:

```
If ((reader.Item("Approved"), True, False) = 0, (reader.Item("DoNotDisplay"), False, False) = 0) Then
```

End if

Comment: No, that didn't work.  Still asking for a parenthesis in the same position